# Check single elements in a list of dictionaries with python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

You have a list of dictionaries like this one:

```
groups = {"1":["Susanne", "Laura", "Anna"],
    "2":["Kim", "Lisa", "Kevin"];
    "3": ["Donald", "Hans", "Jack"],
    }
```

How can u check the single elements, like for example: How many of the names are starting with an "A"
I tried everything, but I always get errors...

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: Post code, we'll help you fix it, but we wont do it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can flatten the inner lists and take check how many satisfy the condition in a list comnprehension:

```
sum(i.startswith('A') for i in [s for l in groups.values() for s in l])
# 1
```

---

The above would be equivalent to the following for loop:

```
c = 0
for l in groups.values():
    for s in l:
           if s.startswith('A'):
                c += 1
```

Comment: hey, ty for the answer. i need a solution without importing anything, I think it should be possible, but I dont get how. ( Pretty new to python)

Comment: You can also flatten with a nested list comprehension @M0NX (see update)

Comment: awesome, ty. the loop was exactly what I searched for :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
sum(map(lambda x:x.startswith('A'),sum(groups.values(),[])))
#1
```